# Quartz Job throttling

Tags: concurrency, quartz-scheduler, jobs, throttling

Little bit wiered requirement:

I have a few quartz jobs that are acting as data collectors, collects data from different locations as and when available. Then I have another job [data load] which is being called/triggered from the collector jobs to update my DB.

My requirement is to some how throttle Load Job to have only two instances running in parallel and handle the work coming from the collector jobs

Collector Jobs 1,2,...N   > Loader Job (two instances)

Job programs are deployed in clusted Tomcat.

Two Questions:
1) How can I make the Collector jobs to wait, when two instances of the Loader job already in process? Is there any way to use the quartz program to impelement FIFO logic to throttle the work to Loader job? I also do not want the collector to pick up another data, if one is already waiting to be processed.
2) Is there any way to run a job with two threads only? No more than two instances should be active at a time? I have limitation on my DB table to run only two instances in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

It's 8 years later and the question shows up as the top result in google when searching for job throttling. And while the case from question clearly begs for using a queue, the actual answer was never given.

So... To throttle jobs in quartz one has to use `TriggerListener` and implement the throttling in `vetoJobExecution`. The job itself can also be annotated to prevent concurrent executions with `@DisallowConcurrentExecution`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a producer-consumer situation here. 
The producer and the consumer are usually separated by a queue. Have your collectors put items into a (persistent?) queue and have your Loader reading from the queue and dispatching up to 2 handling threads.

Comment: It is a producer-consumer situation here. But the objective was to avoid the intermediate queue, I want to process only what I can process from the producer locations. That way producers can know what is still waiting to be picked up.

Comment: Even if there is a queue, the producers can poll it to know there is stuff in there. If you want more guidance, you need to clarify a bit what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: We have an application which has few standalone java programs (20+ programs) which are continuously looking at input folders. They pick up the files, and then hand them out to worker threads. Only one worker program available, and we can allow only two instances of it to run at time due cuncurrency issues on the DB resources. We are using Java threads to handle the throttling to worker threads. What we are trying to do is to get away with standalobe programs, and convert them to Quartz batch programs deployed on webserver. Also we are trying to remove threads on a clustered environment.

Comment: I see. You have a variation of the producer consumer pattern, where the producer is not supposed to be eager. i.e. it should produce data only when there is a consumer that is ready to take care of it. In order to implement it over a scheduling mechanism, you can have your consumer schedule the producer for a single execution on demand (instead of periodic execution). That being said, I think this would be an abuse to the scheduling mechanism. You are basically trying to implement an async pull pattern and use Quartz as a message broker.